# Gsutil : oauth2_plugin missing files ?

Tags: python, gsutil

I am trying to use the gsutil library in my code and have followed the installation instructions on the google website carefully

However, even with the correct PYTHONPATH set, when I run the line

```
from gslib.third_party.oauth2_plugin import oauth2_plugin
```

I get the error

```
No module named gslib.third_party.oauth2_plugin
```

I looked inside the folder structure and indeed there is no folder in that location. So, is Google shipping bad code or what, as no where on their installation does it show you how or where to install this missing folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908745/unable-to-import-gsutil). For non-GAE apps you should use [Cloud Storage JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/), for [GAE GCS client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/) is the best choice.